# How to resolve incorrect parameters from LambdaMetafactory

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I'm trying to execute annotated method within main method in App.java with **LambdaMetafactory.metafactory()**:

```
import com.drfits.annotation.RunMethod;
import com.drfits.transfer.Transfer;
import com.drfits.transfer.TransferExecutor;
import com.drfits.transfer.TransferExecutorImpl;
import com.drfits.transfer.TransferImpl;

import java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.function.Function;

/**
 * Application for execute annotated method
 */
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Transfer transfer = new TransferImpl("Hello, World!");
        Method[] methods = TransferExecutorImpl.class.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            RunMethod annotation = method.getAnnotation(RunMethod.class);
            if (annotation != null) {
                try {
                    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
                    MethodHandle methodHandle = lookup.unreflect(method);
                    MethodType invokedType = MethodType.methodType(Function.class);
                    MethodType functionMethodType = MethodType.methodType(method.getReturnType(), method.getParameterTypes());

                    // Lambda which can be executed
                    TransferExecutor transferExecutor= new TransferExecutorImpl();
                    Function<Transfer, Void> commonLambda = transferExecutor::execute;
                    commonLambda.apply(transfer);

                    // Lambda constructed manually
                    Function<Transfer, Void> constructedLambda = (Function) LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
                            lookup,
                            "apply",
                            invokedType,
                            functionMethodType,
                            methodHandle,
                            methodHandle.type()).getTarget().invokeExact();
                    constructedLambda.apply(transfer);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println(t.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm trying to execute this code it'll throw exception:

```
Incorrect number of parameters for instance method invokeVirtual com.drfits.transfer.TransferExecutorImpl.execute:(Transfer)void; 0 captured parameters, 1 functional interface method parameters, 1 implementation parameters
```

Comment: Don't just link to the homepage of a whole project. Post here the code your question is about.

Answer (score 4):

Using the code

```
TransferExecutor transferExecutor= new TransferExecutorImpl();
Function<Transfer, Void> commonLambda = transferExecutor::execute;
```

you are binding the `Function` to a particular instance of `TransferExecutor`. Your dynamic creation code lacks an instance for the invocation of the instance method `TransferExecutorImpl.execute`. That’s what the exception tries to tell you.

An instance method needs a target instance to be invoked on, hence your target method has a functional signature of `(TransferExecutor,Transfer)→Void`.

You can either, create a `BiFunction<TransferExecutor,Transfer, Void>` out of this method or bind an instance to it like with your `transferExecutor::execute` method reference. For the latter

- change the invoked type to receive an instance of `TransferExecutor`

  ```
  MethodType invokedType = MethodType.methodType(
                               Function.class, TransferExecutorImpl.class);
  ```
- provide the argument at the invocation:

  ```
  … .getTarget().invokeExact((TransferExecutorImpl)transferExecutor);
  ```

Note that there is still a subtle difference. The statement `Function<Transfer, Void> commonLambda = transferExecutor::execute;` refers to the interface method while the method you have identified via your annotation is the method declared in `TransferExecutorImpl`.

Regarding binding captured values, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27605965/2711488) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30641031/2711488) for more explanation and examples.

Answer (score 1):

The error is trying to tell you are not passing another parameters. It expects one, but you are not passing it one.

I suggest you look at the parameters you are passing and compare them to the parameters actually passed when building a lambda.

Write what you are trying to do and a lambda first and see what parameters you should be passing.

Comment: I couldn't find a mistake within parameters therefore I've asked for help with code above.

Comment: @EvgeniyFitsner did you try my suggestion of comparing your details to the ones the compiler generates?